# Como probar la lógica de un controller en su IActionResult Create con una prueba unitaria con Moq en ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, pruebas-unitarias

Estoy queriendo realizar una prueba unitaria que verifique el funcionamiento de la acción crear en mi controlador, tengo separada la lógica del proyecto web y estoy utilizando inyección de dependencias el método que hace el guardado esta en un IService y este retorna un booleano si se crea con exito o no el metodo es el siguiente

```
public class DifuntoService : IDifuntoService
{
    private readonly ParroquiaDbContext _context;

    public DifuntoService(ParroquiaDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool Create(Difunto model)
    {           
          try
        {                
            _context.Difunto.Add(model);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            foreach(var sacramento in model.SacramentosCheckeados)
            {                   
                if (sacramento.checkboxSelect == true)
                {
                    var difuntoSacramento = new DifuntoSacramento
                    {
                        DifuntoId = model.DifuntoId,
                        SacramentoId = sacramento.SacramentoId
                    };

                    _context.DifuntoSacramento.Add(difuntoSacramento);
                }

            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

El controlador está así

```
public class DifuntosController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDifuntoService _difuntoService;

    public DifuntosController(IDifuntoService difuntoService)
    {
        _difuntoService = difuntoService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(DifuntoViewModel model)
    {
        //Parseando Fechas de String a DateTime
        DateTime fechaNacimientoParsed = DateTime.ParseExact(model.FechaNacimiento, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

        Difunto persistencia = new Difunto
        {                
            FechaCreacion = DateTime.Now,
            NombreCompleto = model.NombreCompleto,
            FechaNacimiento = fechaNacimientoParsed,
            EstadoCivilId = model.EstadoCivilId,
            NombreConyuge = model.NombreConyuge,
            NombrePadres = model.NombrePadres,
            NombreHijos = model.NombreHijos,
            Comunidad = model.Comunidad,
            CargoEnIglesia = model.CargoEnIglesia,
            TipoMuerteId = model.TipoMuerteId,
            SacramentosCheckeados = model.Sacramentos
        };

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var listas = new DifuntoViewModel
            {
                EstadosCivil = _difuntoService.GetEstadoCivil(),
                TiposMuerte = _difuntoService.GetTipoMuerte(),
                Sacramentos = (List<Sacramento>)_difuntoService.GetSacramentos()
            };


            return View("Create", model);
        }

        _difuntoService.Create(persistencia);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Y lo que estoy intentando probar es cuando se crea un nuevo objeto este retorna true pero no se que está mal no se como finalizar el metodo esta es la prueba unitaria, estoy usando moq

```
[TestClass]
public class DifuntosControllerTest
{    
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateDifunto_Test()
    {
        //Arrange
        var mockService = new Mock<IDifuntoService>();

        var difuntoNew = new Difunto()
        {
            NombreCompleto = "Abner Gónzales",
            NombreConyuge = "Juana López",
            NombrePadres = "Albert Uraya Me Espanto y Luisa Me Espanto",
            NombreHijos = "Juan, Daniel y Gabriel Gónzales",
            Comunidad = "El coco",
            CargoEnIglesia = "Diacono"
        };

        mockService.Setup(test => test.Create(difuntoNew)).Returns(true);
        var controller = new DifuntosController(mockService.Object);

        //Act
        //ViewResult result = controller.Create(GetNewDifuntoViewModel(difuntoNew)) as ViewResult;

        var resultado = controller.Create(GetNewDifuntoViewModel(difuntoNew));


        Assert.IsNotNull(resultado);
    }

    private DifuntoViewModel GetNewDifuntoViewModel(Difunto model)
    {
        return new DifuntoViewModel()
        {
            NombreCompleto = model.NombreCompleto,
            NombreConyuge = model.NombreConyuge,
            NombrePadres = model.NombrePadres,
            NombreHijos = model.NombreHijos,
            Comunidad = model.Comunidad,
            CargoEnIglesia = model.CargoEnIglesia
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Me parece que no es al controlador al que debes realizar la prueba si no al metodo Create de la clase DifuntoService, ya que es la que te va a devolver un resultado. El controlador en el peor de los casos te va a devolver el mismo modelo y en el mejor te va a redirigir. Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que ocurre si el metodo Create retorna false? Creo que tendrías que controlar eso. En el caso que quieras comparar cosas puedes usar Assert.AreEqual(true, result)

Comment: Tienes razón, ya tengo más claro que lo que debo probar es el método Create del servicio, y no el controlador gracias por tu respuesta, me pregunto si lo que tengo dentro del método CreateDifunto_Test() está bien?? ya que la prueba sigue siendo fallida en su resultado

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas un poco confundido con las pruebas unitarias. el fin de tener IoC y realizar Unit Testing es poder realizar pruebas de forma isolada del resto del sistema, para este caso o pruebas el controlador o pruebas el método del servicio, no ambos y tampoco debes tocar la base de datos con pruebas. en ese caso estarías realizando pruebas integrales. y para ambos casos existen distintas metodologías para realizar las pruebas.

Como apunta IDanny7 al parecer lo que tiene mas lógica de ser probado seria el método del servicio, el problema del método del servicio es que según mi opinión esta acoplado con la capa de acceso a datos, por lo tanto seria un problema probar su comportamiento.

Otro problema es que en servicio tienes al parecer el contexto de forma concreta no abstracta. lo cual tampoco servirá para probar el servicio con mocks y si es así lo único que se ve como candidato a UT es el controlador que carece de lógica para pruebas a menos que solo estés aprendiendo UT no tiene mucho sentido probar el modelstate pero se puede.

acá una explicación de la diferencia de las pruebas que te comento.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357601/whats-the-difference-between-unit-tests-and-integration-tests

mas definiciones de tipos de pruebas
https://codeutopia.net/blog/2015/04/11/what-are-unit-testing-integration-testing-and-functional-testing/

**UPDATE**

Después de ver el caso por mi parte veo complicado integrar UT a la implementación que tienes, quizás deberías considerar pruebas integrales o agregar una capa con el patrón de repositorio que te permita mas fácilmente realizar las pruebas unitarias.

Comment: Gracias manu_rit si tengo claro cuales son las pruebas unitarias y las de integración, el problema es que no me supe explicar en sí lo que necesito probar es lo que esta en el metodo del servicio, lo que no te entiendo a que te refieres cuando dice que tengo el contexto de forma concreta no abstracta? y porque no puedo hacer la prueba con ese método según leí por ahí tener el servicio con mocks es como tener un serviciofake para realizar la prueba y no tocar datos de la db, muchas gracias por tu respuesta manu_rit te lo agradezo

Comment: Hola Eduardo, cuando digo concreto o abstracto me refiero a la abstracción de una clase ya sea mediante una clase abstracta o en este caso mas especifico una interfaz. casi todo el mundo usa el patron de repositorio para tener una abstraccion de EF y poder realizar pruebas unitarias mas simple, ahora por lo que veo tambien existen formas de hacerlo como lo estas intentando. Por lo que entiendo en tu caso la forma seria con un dbcontext con propiedades virtuales. y depedera si es code first o dbfirst quizas debas modificar los templates t4. te dejo un link con lo que te comento.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx, que version de EF usas?

Comment: Es code-first, y la versión 2.0.2 Entity Framework Core, aún no he logrado hacer esa prueba unitaria.